# fetch 1 0r 0 for each records passed in where clause

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with jsonb column datatype

```
+-----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id  |             value                                                              |
+-----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1   | {"t1": "val", "value": [{"id": "1", "name": "abc"},{"id": "2", "name": "xyz"}] |
| 2   | {"t1": "val", "value": [{"id": "2", "name": "xyz"},{"id": "3", "name": "pqr"}] |
+-----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*
```

```
SELECT 'True' as status 
FROM   table t
where t.value->'value'->-1 -> 'id' IN ('"2"','"1"')
```

I want to fetch Ture or false along with each id checked in where clause.

Kindly help me in this query

Comment: Which Postgres version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the condition into the SELECT list, but you have to iterate over all array elements:

```
select t.id, 
       exists(select * 
              from jsonb_array_elements(t.value -> 'value') as v(item) 
              where item ->> 'id' in ('1','2')) as status
from the_table t;
```

With Postgres 12 or later, you can extract all IDs into an array and then use the `?|` operator:

```
select t.id, 
       jsonb_path_query_array(t.value -> 'value', '$[*].id') ?| array['1','2'] as status
from the_table t;
```